# Two insertion instead of one with mgo

Tags: go, mgo

Im new in Golang and Im building a Golang CRUD using mgo framework to practice. When I insert one element using mgo, is inserted two times instead of one time, I ckecked it in MongoDB Compass Community. This is my [repository](https://github.com/edualb/MongoDB-Connection-With-Golang)

This is a picture showing how is being saved in my database:

[image]

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code inserts a single document only. If it would insert 2, properties (except the `_id` field) would be identical / same.

And your 2 documents have different `time` field, thus they are from 2 different runs.

So what you see is the result of 2 different runs (2 seconds away from each other), either by you or by your IDE.

Comment: Thanks so much! You gave me the key word. My antivirus ran my main.go two times, when I disabled it works fine.